# One Regex for 2 different text c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have 2 strings. and I need **one** Regex for both.

```
s1="The 8481D provides extraordinary accuracy, stability, and lower SWR.";

s2="<li>Complete with case and 9V battery</li><div id='warranty'><img src='1yr.gif'>";
```

I need to get all characters of s1 and the characters of s2 till the characters: `<div id='warranty'>`

so, it will be:

```
    s1="The 8481D provides extraordinary accuracy, stability, and lower SWR.";

    s2="<li>Complete with case and 9V battery</li>";
```

I thought of: `.+?(?<=<div id="warranty">)` but I got just the s2 string, also `.+?(?<=<div id="warranty">|\.)` didn't work, I got s1, but got too much characters in s2.

Comment: Which programming language? Different host languages support different regex dialects.

Comment: you said "and the characters of s2 til the characters: `'"'`", but then say you wanted to finish at </li>?

Comment: Does it have to be Regex? It would be easier using functions like `strpos` and `substr`.

Comment: @jared, It finish at </li>, but not always, the characters that always will be are `"<div id='warranty'>"`

Comment: The second string looks like HTML. Were you aware that Regex is probably [not the best tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to parse HTML? Have you tried using a HTML parser such as HTML Agility Pack?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, I use HTML Agility Pack, and after that I must use Regex to clean the string-node.

Comment: No, you don't need to use Regex. If you already use HTML Agility Pack use it to the end extract the information you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.+?(?=<div\sid='warranty'>|\.)
```

or if you want to include and dot regex will be:

```
^.+?(?=<div\sid='warranty'>|$)
```

Comment: There is a difference. Try it again.

Comment: or if you want to include and dot regex will be:
^.+?(?=<div\sid='warranty'>|$)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this in C# is using `IndexOf` and `Substring` methods (if you not insist on `Regex`):

```
static String GetValidString(String inputString)
{
    int end = inputString.IndexOf("<div id='warranty'>");
    if (end == -1)
        end = inputString.Length;
    return inputString.Substring(0, end);
}
```